# What is the expamapi.dll in windows folder?

Tags: windows, malware

I'm getting a virus message related to expamapi.dll in c:\Windows (windows xp).  When I used ProcessExplorer, this dll is related to a bunch of processes, which isn't making sense. Some of the processes listed are:

- explorer.exe
- svchost.exe
- MOM.exe
- CTDVDDET.exe
- CTSysVol.exe
- DLLML.exe
- CTHELPER.EXE
- Dropbox.exe

So, does this make sense? Or do I need to do some deep cleaning?

Comment: are you 100% certain thats the file name ? the only google result for expamapi.dll is this page, which is really Odd...

Comment: Agreed - I was just about to post that exact question for Greg.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. And this is what is causing me confusion as well...what the hell is this thing? That file is in the Windows folder and apparently associated with all of those processes, according to ProcessExplorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a related question on the BitDefender forum and they confirmed that this is a malicious file. A deep scan removed it.

http://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?showtopic=21462&st=0&gopid=93849&#entry93849